# Sending multiple emails with different receiver and content

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, email

I have an excel spreadsheet, which looks something like that:

```
e1@xxx.com - ID1
e2@xxx.com - ID2
e3@xxx.com - ID3
e4@xxx.com - ID4
e5@xxx.com - ID5
e6@xxx.com - ID6
e7@xxx.com - ID7
```

Any way I could send like 100-200 emails like that with just submitting my table content? Or any suggestions how to do that. Sending 200 emails manually is a little bit too much work for my project.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small nodeJS script (considering that you want to send the same or a similar email to all clients) that does exactly that. The module nodemailer found on npm can use your email server or even your email account on some public service ( gmail etc ). You can find the TL;DR code to send emails using nodemailer here: https://nodemailer.com/about/. I sadly do not know a specific way to import all the emails from the excel into the node application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a mail merge. I can explain here but the Microsoft pretty much covers it. It's all [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3)

Essentially, save the excel as a .csv select your mail recipients field and then select ID field. This will allow you to customize what you want in the text. Once you click send it will automatically email all recipients via Outlook.